# How to protect a directory from files getting uploaded into it

Tags: .htaccess

I want to prevent uploading files to a specific directory,
as I already have some php and html files in this directory.

I was trying .htacess:

```
Options -Indexes
    <Files *>
      deny from all
    </Files>
```

This is working, but makes me unable to open any files from the folder.
I then tried with this:

```
<Files *.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```

But then I cannot start index.php in this folder...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Linux, use the `chmod` command to disable uploads, but still leave browsing enabled.

Use it like this: `chmod 755 directory_path` or `chmod 555 directory_path`. You may need to become `root` in order to make these changes, depending on your setup.

The first `chmod` command in this example allows only the directory owner to upload files, others can only read the directory contents. The second `chmod` command doesn't allow anyone to write to this directory. For more information, use `man chmod` inside your shell.